# DHTML Scheduler .NET change path script and style files

Tags: vb.net, dhtmlx-scheduler

I started experimenting with [DHTMLX Scheduler .Net](http://scheduler-net.com/) but encountered some 'issues'.
I like to have everything ordered at my own way (css files in folder 'styling', js files in folder 'scripts', ...)

But now it seems like using this dll forces me to place everything in a folder that they chose. So when I init the Scheduler on my page, it automatically tries to call this files:

- /Scripts/dhtmlxScheduler/dhtmlxscheduler.js
- /Scripts/dhtmlxScheduler/dhtmlxscheduler.css
- /Scripts/dhtmlxScheduler/locale/locale_nl.js

I would like to change these paths to for example '/scripts/dhtmlxscheduler.js' but I can't find a property in the Scheduler object where I'm able to do this.

Is this possible or do I have to put everything in the folder they would like to have it?

My working code thisfar:

```
Public Scheduler As DHXScheduler
        Scheduler = New DHXScheduler()
        Scheduler.InitialDate = New DateTime(Now.Year, Now.Month, Now.Day)
        Scheduler.InitialView = "day"
        Scheduler.Config.first_hour = 6
        Scheduler.Config.last_hour = 20
        Scheduler.Config.time_step = 30
        Scheduler.Config.limit_time_select = True
        Scheduler.Localization.Set(SchedulerLocalization.Localizations.Dutch)

        Scheduler.DataAction = Me.ResolveUrl("/Handlers/Scheduler_Data.ashx")
        Scheduler.SaveAction = Me.ResolveUrl("/Handlers/Scheduler_Save.ashx")
        Scheduler.LoadData = True
        Scheduler.EnableDataprocessor = True
```

I would like to find the possibility to set such a property to my own filepath, if possible ..

thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further research showed me that I could change the default location with this line of code:

```
Scheduler.Codebase = "/js/dhtmlxscheduler"
```

However, this only sets the rootfolder, so all the files have to be located within this folder. I helped myself out by putting empty files over there and call my own styling and scripting from the location I wanted (just to get rid of the console errors).

So this solved my problem (as far as it could be solved).